# Extjs store getById return null

Tags: extjs, store

I have a grid panel of Devices, and I am trying to give to the devices a floor value which is contained in another store called LatestPosition. I added to the grid the column "floor" and now I want to populate this column with the value from the other store. The positionId in the *Devices* store corresponds to the id of the *LatestPosition* store, so it can be used to find the corresponding position of the device. The problem is that when I try to get the position in the LatestPosition store using the positionId of the device (using `store.getById`)I have null as a return value, even if this value seems to exist (screenshot below):

[image]

so the value I need is not null, but somehow I can not access to it.

This is my code:

```
updateDevices:function(){          

     Ext.getStore('Devices').each(function (device) {
        var positionId = device.get('positionId');

        console.log(Ext.getStore('LatestPositions').getData().items);

       Ext.getStore('LatestPositions').on('load', function() {
          position = Ext.getStore('LatestPositions').getById('positionId');
        });

        //position is always null!

        if (position) {
            console.log(position.get('attributes').floor);
            floor =  position.get('attributes').floor;
        } else {
            floor =  0;
        }

        device.set({
           "floor": floor
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Maybe, you should create a sencha fiddle sample.https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Comment: Whats the id of the record you are showing? I guess you need to set the idProperty of the model to your positionId accordingly. More about this here: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-idProperty

Answer (score 0):

`getById` argument should be `positionId` instead of string 'positionId'.

```js
updateDevices:function(){          

     Ext.getStore('Devices').each(function (device) {
        var positionId = device.get('positionId');

        console.log(Ext.getStore('LatestPositions').getData().items);

       Ext.getStore('LatestPositions').on('load', function() {
          position = Ext.getStore('LatestPositions').getById(positionId);
        });

        //position is always null!

        if (position) {
            console.log(position.get('attributes').floor);
            floor =  position.get('attributes').floor;
        } else {
            floor =  0;
        }

        device.set({
           "floor": floor
        });
    });
},
```